# Database not getting created

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I cannot get the database to get created when I start my `asp core` application, even though I was able to do it before on a different project.

My context class is called `DatabaseContext`

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
    {
        public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    }

DbInitializer.cs

public class DbInitializer
    {
        public static void Initialize(DatabaseContext context)
        {
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();

            if (context.People.Any())
            {
                return;   // DB has been seeded
            }

            var people = new Person[]
            {
            new Person{ FirstName = "John", LastName = "Johnson", Age = 32, Email = "john@gmail.com", Subscribed = true},
            new Person{ FirstName = "Bob", LastName = "Bobson", Age = 22, Email = "bob@gmail.com", Subscribed = false},
            new Person{ FirstName = "Sally", LastName = "Jackson", Age = 26, Email = "sally@gmail.com", Subscribed = false},
            };

            foreach (Person p in people)
            {
                context.People.Add(p);
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

appsettings.json

"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=TESTDB;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },

Startup.cs

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddMvc();
        }


Program.cs

public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //BuildWebHost(args).Run();

            var host = BuildWebHost(args);

            using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
                try
                {
                    var context = services.GetRequiredService<DatabaseContext>();
                    DbInitializer.Initialize(context);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                    logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while seeding the database.");
                }
            }
            host.Run();
        }
```

When I run the app, I do not get the database file created in my `Users` folder, nor do I see it in `SQL Server Object Explorer`

Comment: Did you check the sql server instance `(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb` ? Your code looks fine and it should create the db. Is it executing the initializer code (put a breakpoint and findout)

Comment: @Shyju Yea I did. It does get hit (the `DbInitializer.Initialize(context);`). Weird.

Comment: if the code executes succesfully, check the context.Database.Connection property, where you can see which db is targeted.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro Where do I do that?

Comment: Anyway the targeted database should be the one specified in appsettings.json right?

Comment: I did it in another project with another Context name, maybe the name `DatabaseContext` was confusing it.

Comment: the database should be the one given to your context, but since it wasnt created this suggests it takes the connection string from somewhere else. You can inspect the Connection.connectionstring property in debug mode or simply let your program write it down (if you expose the property - if not, cast it to DbContext beforehand)